# InstallShield 2016 not installing Service

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, installshield-2016

I am trying to configure and install a service in InstallShield 2016. I added the service using the component wizard. When I ran the installer, the Window Installer popup appeared on my screen with the different options that could be passed to the service. How do I passed these options to the service? 
I've tried creating the service using the component wizard and without the component wizard. In both case, it was the same outcome as described above. I have been unsuccessfully looking for explanation on how to do it.

**Screenshots of the settings and popup window:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to install your installation's launcher as a service? Normally you would install an exe or dll (that is placed on the machine by your installation) as a service.

Comment: There is an exe and an msi files that are placed on a folder in the target machine. I am trying to lunch that exe file.

Comment: Is that exe a service, or an installation launcher? The fact that MSI appears (presumably when this file is invoked; verify with a tool like procmon if you're uncertain) suggests that it is the latter.

Comment: You are right. It is not service but an installation launcher. I deleted the installation project and created a fresh one. It did not show that window anymore, but it gave error "2731". Then, I restarted my computer, and I had several messages from syswow64. I clicked on view message, the installation window for the service came up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get this to work.  I am a novice to Installshield. This was my very first time using it.

1. Michael Urman comment was very helpful.
2. I've read the documentation on how to launch msi using msiexec.exe, and I am still confused. According to the documentation, deferred action must be between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize and return processing should be synchronous(wait exit code). However, the system complained that there is another installation in progress, so it would not install the service.
3. In order to get around this, I set the working directory to [service] (the folder that contains my msi and exe files), I set the command line to msiexec.exe /i "[SERVICE]UserAgent.msi" /qn,  I set returning processing to Asynchronous (no wait for completion), Install Exec Sequence to after schedule reboot, and add a condition to check for not installed.
4. With these options, I was able to silently installed the service. However, it will not uninstall when uninstalling the application. It has to be manually uninstall

Answer (score 1):

That error dialog box is displayed when an msiexec command line is incorrect. It's not clear what you are doing, but you do not run an msiexec command on a service or any exe file. You build an MSI file then install it, and that MSI file will install the service.  Even if you ARE running an msiexec command line on an MSI file you built, it is incorrect.

Comment: No, I am not running an msiexec and or passing any command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For the records:

Check, if the file is marked as "key file". This was my fault.